# Meteor Flow Router setting up example.com/singlePostPage

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, flow-router

I can not manage to create the routes to show a single post with flowrouter and blaze in Meteor.

This is what I have so far which I am sure its mostly wrong!

`publications.js`

```
Meteor.publish('singlePost', function (postId) {
  return Posts.find({ _id: postId });
});
```

`Router.js`

```
FlowRouter.route("/posts/:_id", {
    name: "postPage",
    subscriptions: function (params, queryParams) {
     this.register('postPage', Meteor.subscribe('singlePost'));
 },
    action: function(params, queryParams) {
        BlazeLayout.render("nav", {yield: "postPage"} )
    }
});
```

`singlePost.JS`

```
Template.postPage.helpers({
  thisPost: function(){
    return Posts.findOne();
  }
});
```

`singlePost.html`

```
<template name="postPage">
  {{#with thisPost}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

I used to do it back then with Iron router but now got confused with Flow router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't use the FlowRouter subscriptions. That will soon be deprecated. Use Meteor PubSub. First in the routes.js:

```
    // http://app.com/posts/:_id
    FlowRouter.route('/posts/:id', {
        name: "postPage",
        action: function(params, queryParams) {
            BlazeLayout.render("nav", {yield: "postPage"} )
        }
    });
```

Then when the template is created you subscribe using Meteor's subscription:

```
// Template onCreated
Template.postPage.onCreated(function() {
    // Subscribe only the relevant subscription to this page
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() { // Stops all current subscriptions
        var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id'); // Get the collection id from the route parameter
        self.subscribe('singlePost', id); // Subscribe to the single entry in the collection with the route params id
    });
});
```

Then the helper will be:

```
// Template helper functions
Template.postPage.helpers({
    thisPost: function() {
        // Get the single entry from the collection with the route params id
        var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        var post = Posts.findOne({ // Get the selected entry data from the collection with the given id.
            _id: id
        }) || {};
        return post;
    }
});
```

You also need to check if the subscriptions are ready in html.

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{#with thisPost}}
        <li>{{title}}</li>
    {{/with}}
{{else}}
    <p>nothing to show</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks but still won't work...how the publish function knows what is a postId? I didn't defined it anywhere...I actually was copying some parts of the code from other places to make it work but I think that is the part where I am most confused...thanks

Comment: Hang on, I'm editing my comment 'cause I've noticed other things. Don't worry, I also had this issue. Wait just a sec ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and comments! its working now perfectly! and I will start learning all that since it will be mandatory for every app ;) have a good day

Comment: No problem ;) I actually recommend you using this as part of your boilerplate for Meteor apps. It is from mine :) I only had to change events into posts and that was it.